# LaTeX/BibTeX do not like a certain URL

Tags: bibtex, urls, bibdesk

I have a Bibtex entry that contains a URL that latex does not like: 
http://www-nlpir.nist.gov/projects/duc/duc2007/assessor.update_summarization.instructions.pdf

I get this error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.16 ...sor.update_summarization.instructions.pdf}
```

I am using the report document class. I'm sure `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` is the only package I have used that relates to referencing.

Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Please give us more information and welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Which packages have you loaded related to bibtex?

Comment: It might be the underscore, but why are you making people guess? Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) in order to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The underscore `_` is the problem. Normally the underscore is only allowed in math mode to start an index. That is why LaTeX/BibTex reports the error. You should escape the underscore, i.\,e. write `\_`.

BUT, I guess from your question that you are doing somehing fundamentally wrong. Normally, there is the special field `url={}` that should be used in a bib-file, if you need to point to an url. If you use this special field the underscore and some other characters that are frequently used in urls but have a special meaning in LaTeX (e.g. the %-sign) are escaped automatically.

Comment: `Url = {http://www-nlpir.nist.gov/projects/duc/duc2007/assessor.update_summarization.instructions.pdf}` is in the bib-file.

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide us with the full BibTex-entry and with the full preamble of your main document. Otherwise we cannot help you. Normally, the `url={}` field is supposed to automatically take care of the special symbols. If it does not something else is wrong. But we can only trace the root of the problem, if we have a complete working minimal example.